# Multiple rails servers

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Is it possible to run several rails applications on one computer at the same time? I need to have one running, but would like to debug/test another one without having to turn off the first one.

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yet it is, start them on a different port:

```
rails server -p 3001
```

Answer (score 3):

couple of ways:

```
# start on port 3000
rails server

#start on 3001, get to on http://localhost:3001
rails server -p 3001
```

Use http://pow.cx

1. http://server1.dev
2. http://server2.dev

Answer (score 0):

Absolutely.  Probably the easiest way to do it is using virtual hosts if you are using Apache.

Answer (score 0):

You have a few standard options, but the most common are [Passenger](http://www.modrails.com/) for OS X and Linux, and [pow](http://pow.cx/) for OS X.

You can also use `rails server` on different port numbers and leave it running in the background if you're looking for something quick and dirty.